# Solr / Solritas 3.6 /solr/browse Not Found Issues

Tags: solr, solritas

I have installed a solr instance with Jetty, and  also I tried to follow the instructions here to install the [velocityResponseWriter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/VelocityResponseWriter) I just inserted the jar library that was missing the [Apache Solr Velocity](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr/solr-velocity/3.6.0) and when I start the service via console I get the message that the plugin was loaded ok.

but when I tried to run the solritas I got the following error:

HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /solr/browse. Reason:

```
NOT_FOUND
```

Powered by Jetty://

Any ideas?

Edit: I've been trying to do that over solr 4.0 this is the file configuration section for solritas

```
<requestHandler name="/browse" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>

   <!-- VelocityResponseWriter settings -->
   <str name="wt">velocity</str>
   <str name="v.template">browse</str>
   <str name="v.layout">layout</str>
   <str name="title">Solritas</str>

   <!-- Query settings -->
   <str name="defType">edismax</str>
   <str name="qf">
      text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
      title^10.0 description^5.0 keywords^5.0 author^2.0 resourcename^1.0
   </str>
   <str name="df">text</str>
   <str name="mm">100%</str>
   <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
   <str name="rows">10</str>
   <str name="fl">*,score</str>

   <str name="mlt.qf">
     text^0.5 features^1.0 name^1.2 sku^1.5 id^10.0 manu^1.1 cat^1.4
     title^10.0 description^5.0 keywords^5.0 author^2.0 resourcename^1.0
   </str>
   <str name="mlt.fl">text,features,name,sku,id,manu,cat,title,description,keywords,author,resourcename</str>
   <int name="mlt.count">3</int>

   <!-- Faceting defaults -->
   <str name="facet">on</str>
   <str name="facet.field">cat</str>
   <str name="facet.field">manu_exact</str>
   <str name="facet.field">content_type</str>
   <str name="facet.field">author_s</str>
   <str name="facet.query">ipod</str>
   <str name="facet.query">GB</str>
   <str name="facet.mincount">1</str>
   <str name="facet.pivot">cat,inStock</str>
   <str name="facet.range.other">after</str>
   <str name="facet.range">price</str>
   <int name="f.price.facet.range.start">0</int>
   <int name="f.price.facet.range.end">600</int>
   <int name="f.price.facet.range.gap">50</int>
   <str name="facet.range">popularity</str>
   <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.start">0</int>
   <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.end">10</int>
   <int name="f.popularity.facet.range.gap">3</int>
   <str name="facet.range">manufacturedate_dt</str>
   <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.start">NOW/YEAR-10YEARS</str>
   <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.end">NOW</str>
   <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.gap">+1YEAR</str>
   <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.other">before</str>
   <str name="f.manufacturedate_dt.facet.range.other">after</str>

   <!-- Highlighting defaults -->
   <str name="hl">on</str>
   <str name="hl.fl">content features title name</str>
   <str name="hl.encoder">html</str>
   <str name="hl.simple.pre">&lt;b&gt;</str>
   <str name="hl.simple.post">&lt;/b&gt;</str>
   <str name="f.title.hl.fragsize">0</str>
   <str name="f.title.hl.alternateField">title</str>
   <str name="f.name.hl.fragsize">0</str>
   <str name="f.name.hl.alternateField">name</str>
   <str name="f.content.hl.snippets">3</str>
   <str name="f.content.hl.fragsize">200</str>
   <str name="f.content.hl.alternateField">content</str>
   <str name="f.content.hl.maxAlternateFieldLength">750</str>

   <!-- Spell checking defaults -->
   <str name="spellcheck">on</str>
   <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">false</str>       
   <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
   <str name="spellcheck.alternativeTermCount">2</str>
   <str name="spellcheck.maxResultsForSuggest">5</str>       
   <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
   <str name="spellcheck.collateExtendedResults">true</str>  
   <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">5</str>
   <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">3</str>           
 </lst>

 <!-- append spellchecking to our list of components -->
 <arr name="last-components">
   <str>spellcheck</str>
 </arr>
```

Comment: What is the full url you pasted. localhost:8983/solr/browse ?

Comment: yes the Url is localhost:8080/solr/browse, Now I'm trying to set up a new core, I see theres a configuration section in the file and there's a request handler for the browse, but I'm getting the 404 error anyway, is there any aditional step to perform that I miss, at the moment I'm trying with solr 4.0 as well, but with any luck.

Comment: Hopefully the 8080 is a typo in your comment. The default port for solr is 8983

Comment: I setted up the port to 8080, but I've copied the folder /velocity content to the solr folder inside tomcat, it's working now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your default search field is equal to 'text' : `<str name="df">text</str>`, you maybe have to change it to one of your fields.
Check the command line from which you have launched start.jar (Solr), to see the exact error.